# How to open links always in default container in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, multi-account-containers

Using **Firefox**, I created a container for Google.

If I do a Google search and open a link from there (either in a new tab or in the same one), it will open in the very same container, thus enabling Google to track me on the opened website.

What I'd like to achieve is to make Firefox open links from a **non-default container** in a **default container** tab (that is, to only use containers other than the default one for websites which I specifically assign to those containers).

Is this possible either by staying in the **same tab** *or* opening the link in a **new tab** but **without manually specifying** the default container for the new tab (i.e. from the context menu)?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I'm using [an extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-SE/firefox/addon/dont-track-me-google1) that converts the Google search result links from their *google.com* form to the actual target URL-s, so that kind of tracking is ignorable in the above example.

Comment: there's an add on for this - see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There's an add-on for what you want to do

The ["Google Container" add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-container/) does wat you ask for:

> How does it work?
>   Installing this extension deletes your Google cookies and logs you out of Google.
>   The next time you navigate to Google it will load in a new red colored browser tab (the “Container”).
>   You can log in and use Google normally when in the Google Container. **If you click on a non-Google link or navigate to a non-Google website in the URL bar, these pages will load outside of the container.**
>   Clicking Google Share buttons on other browser tabs will load them within the Google Container. You should know that using these buttons passes information to Google about the website that you shared from.

You can get it [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-container/)

### (previous answer)

Even if you find some way to do what you describe, in the precise Google context you mention it wouldn't make any sense:
if you take a closer look at the Google search results (e.g. hover on the link and see the target displayed at the bottom of your browser window)**, all the clickable links lead to google.com, and have as parameters some session cookie plus the target website.
These are NOT direct links to your target website, it's Google's server which will redirect you to your destination !
So, even if you open those links in a private window, Google will still know its you that requested that link!

**EDIT: the mechanism is a little bit more subtle. At first, a hoover will display the link to your website. BUT as soon as you try to click them (try a right-click!) that link will be substituted with a link to google.com!

.. Google's engineers thought faster than you, and be sure that if today you find some hole in their tracking, tomorrow they will close it: it's their business, in ALL senses.

The only way to avoid search-engine tracking is to use a privacy- aware service such as [duckduckgo.com](https://duckduckgo.com/) or [qwant.com](https://qwant.com/)

Comment: Dear 1NN, sorry, please take a look at the edit I made to the question.
Though, the Google case was only an example case, I could say that if I open a search result (which thus opens still in the Google container) and open a link from that site, that still will be opened in the very same container. This chain of remaining in that container is what I'd like to prevent.

Comment: Thank you for the edits! So you believe there is no such built-in functionality in Firefox? I found this issue regarding the question (but your extension looks fine): https://github.com/mozilla/multi-account-containers/issues/847